# Intersection of focal radii and tangents on an ellipse

Tags: geometry, conic-sections

If SP and S’P’  are focal radii of an ellipse drawn in the same direction, and the tangents at P and P’meet S’P’,SP in Q’ and Q respectively, is the line Q’Q parallel to P’P? I have calculated the gradient of PP’ as $$-[x’[b^2]/[y’[a^2]$$ where (x’,y’) are the coordinates of the intersection of PQ’ and P’Q, but can’t seem to show QQ’ has equal gradient. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please include the work you did to get the result you have so far. This can help people avoid wasting time duplicating your effort, and it will give a sense of the kind of approach with which you are comfortable.

Comment: I used the well known result concerning the chord connecting the two points of tangency from an exterior point of an ellipse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The proof is quite simple if we employ a very useful property of the ellipse:

> the line joining the intersection point $T$ of the tangents at $P$ and
>   $P'$, with the midpoint $M$ of $PP'$, passes through the center $O$ of
>   the ellipse.

As $O$ is the midpoint of $SS'$, then line $TO$ is parallel to $QS$ and $Q'S'$. Hence $T$ is the midpoint of both $PQ'$ and $P'Q$, and consequently $PP'Q'Q$ is a parallelogram.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this elegant solution,much appreciated.